# ngtools/webpack: possible to get more details?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am having issues on an app I'm building using webpack & willing to build it as AOT.

I understand that having non-AOT modules in my app can make this fail, and I am suspecting that

But the output I got from webpack/ngtools is only:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './../compiled/src/app/app.module.ngfactory'

And nothing more.

Is there any ways to easily diagnose that, output more details during build to find out which of those modules is messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question :)

This was due to the use of non-compatible AOT code within module code:

I was using variable declaration within the module which AOT does not lie as they are not real values;

**Before:**

```
declare var __API_URL__: boolean;
declare var __VERSION__: string;

// Ommitting code

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: __API_URL__ },
    { provide: bypassAuth,  useValue: __VERSION__ },
  ]
  ...
})
```

**After:**

```
export function getConfig() {
  var c = new EnvironmentConfiguration();
  c.ApiUrl = process.env.API_URL;
  c.Version = process.env.VERSION;
  return c;
}

// Ommitting code

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: EnvironmentConfiguration, useFactory: getConfig
    },
  ]
  ...
})
```